# Unable to get pipeline.fit() to work using Sklearn and Keras Wrappers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, data-science, keras-layer

I am getting a value error for parameters (not enough to unpack expected 2 got 1) I have a network I want to train:

```python
def build(self):
    numpy.random.seed(self.seed)
    self.estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler))
    self.estimators.append(('mlp', KerasClassifier(build_fn=self.build_fn, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=0)))
    self.pipeline = Pipeline(self.estimators)
```

Now if I want to fit the data to some values: say self.X, self.Y

```python
self.model = self.pipeline.fit(self.X, self.Y, verbose=1)
```

I get

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/jaehan/PycharmProjects/cerebro/cerebro.py", line 257, in 
<module>
model.run()
File "C:/Users/jaehan/PycharmProjects/cerebro/cerebro.py", line 138, in run
self.model = self.pipeline.fit(self.X, self.Y, verbose=1)
File "C:\Users\jaehan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
File "C:\Users\jaehan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 197, in _fit
step, param = pname.split('__', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I was under the impression I could just run a fit and it would return a history object, which I could save and load at any time

I even tried...

```python
self.pipeline.fit(self.X, self.Y)
```

Which throws...

```python
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

I have no idea what is going on here.

Full Code

```python
class Cerebro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None
        self.build_fn = None
        self.data = None
        self.X = None
        self.Y = None
        #these three are for encoding string values to integer_encodings / one hot encodings
        self.encoder = LabelEncoder()
        self.encodings = {}
        self.one_hot_encodings = {}
        self.seed = numpy.random.seed(7) #this is to ensure we have reproducible results.
        self.estimators = []
        self.pipeline = None
        self.kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=self.seed)
        self.cross_validation_score = 0.0

    def preprocess(self):
        """
        This method will preprocess the dataset we want to train our network on. 

        Example:
            import preproccessing
            ...

            dataset, X, Y = preprocessing.main()


        """

        self.data = pandas.read_csv('src_examples/hwtxn_final_for_influx.txt', sep='\t').values
        self.X = numpy.delete(self.data, 13, axis=1)
        self.Y = self.data[:, 13].astype(numpy.float16)

    def build(self):
        self.build_fn = self.base_model()

        self.preprocess()

        numpy.random.seed(self.seed)
        self.estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
        self.estimators.append(('mlp', KerasClassifier(build_fn=self.build_fn, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=0)))
        self.pipeline = Pipeline(self.estimators)

    def run(self):
        """This will actually take the pipeline (preprocessing standardization, model)
        and fit it to our dataset (X, Y) (We don't need test/train since we are using stratified k fold cross val.)

        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            None
        """

        # this is the 'model'
        # self.pipeline
        print(type(self.pipeline))
        print(self.X.shape)
        self.model = self.pipeline.fit(self.X, self.Y)



    def load(self, fn):
        """This will load a saved model (history object)

        Args:
            fn (filename): represents saved model file
        Returns:
            model (pkl object): represents model

        """
        return pickle.load(open(fn, 'rb'))

    def save(self, fn):
        """This will save a model (history object)

        Args:
            fn (filename): represents a filename to save the model as
        Returns:
            None
        """
        pickle.dump(self.model, open(fn, 'wb'))

    def encode(self, vals, key):
        """ This method will encode a list of values and take a key (representing column name, or index) to save
        in the class object (self.encodings)
        This will help us keep track of encodings we have for values we need to translate/decipher.

        Args:
            vals(np.array): array of values to encode
            key(str): str representing the key used to encode this particular set of values
        Returns:
            transformed values (np.array) representing the encoded versions of values
        """
        # int encoding for non int values
        self.encodings[key] = self.encoder.fit_transform(vals)
        return self.encoder.fit_transform(vals)

    def decoder(self, vals, key):
        """This method will decode the integer_encodings for class variables. It will take vals which
        represents a list of values to decode (i.e. [1,2,3] -- [apple, pear, orange])
        It will also take a key (since every decoding has a corresponding encoding) to find which encoding
        scheme to map to

        Args:
            vals(np.array) : array of values to decode
            key(str) : string representing the key used for encoding the values (for decoding it)
        Returns:
            inverse transform of encoded values (np.array)
        """
        # translate int encodings to original values (encoder._classes)
        return self.encodings[key].inverse_transform(vals)

    def cross_validate(self):
        """
        This will perform a cross validation score using a stratified kfold method. (Think traditional Kfold but
        with the values evenly distributed for each subsample)

        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            None
        """
        self.cross_validation_score = cross_val_score(self.pipeline, self.X, self.Y, cv=self.kfold)
        return self.cross_validation_score

    @staticmethod
    def base_model():
        """
        This will return a base model for us to try. The good thing about this implementation is that
        when we decide we want something more complex then all we have to do is define a class function and replace
        the values in the build f(x)

        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            model (keras.models.Sequential): Keras based DNN Model
        """

        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=60, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

    @staticmethod
    def one_hot_encoder(int_encoding):
        """
        This will take an integer encoding of string variables (traditional preprocessing step, will probably
        move this to the preprocessing package.
        Essential it returns a binary 'one hot' encoding of the values we wish to encode

        Example
        #Dataset Values
        [apple, orange, pear]
        #Integer Encoding
        [1, 2, 3]
        #One Hot Encoding
        [[1, 0, 0]
         [0, 1, 0]
         [0, 0, 1]]

        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            Matrix (np.array): matrix representing one hot vectors for a class of values
        """
        # we might not need this... so for now we will keep it static
        return OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(int_encoding.reshape(len(int_encoding), 1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Step 1 is to initialize class (with seed == 7)
    model = Cerebro()
    model.build()
    model.cross_validate()
    print("Here are our estimators:\n {}".format(model.estimators))
    print("Here is our pipeline:\n {}".format(model.pipeline))
    model.run()
```

**EDIT**
The answer is that .fit() build_fn argument requires a function pointer and not the model itself.

**IMHO** I feel an error should be thrown for specifically that case.

Comment: add some data so that we can reproduce the error

Comment: self should exclusively be a keyword in classes. This is really confusing. Could you provide the properties of self? Besides where is this related to sklearn-pandas?

Comment: The last error "`'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fit'
`" suggests that somewhere you changed the pipeline object and assigned data array to it. Show the full code

Comment: Just added full code @seralouk

Comment: Sorry I was trying to be concise. I should have mentioned this was a class implementation @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: @VivekKumar Understood, I looked at the type of the object and it shows sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline object. I do agree though that the error indicates that the pipeline object was changed

Comment: The code you provided dont match the stack trace of error:-`"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"`. If you edit the code, we cant help you.

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the following line:

`self.build_fn = self.base_model()`

This should actually be:

```
self.build_fn = self.base_model
```

KerasClassifier requires a pointer to the function which creates the model, but by appending `()` at the end, you are assigning `build_fn` with the actual model, which is wrong.

Now in addition to above error, I would recommend checking the following lines in your code, which if not corrected will give error in future when you will use the code.

1) `self.encodings[key] = self.encoder.fit_transform(vals)`

Here you are assigning the transformed data to the `encodings[key]` not the model. So when you do this:-

`self.encodings[key].inverse_transform(vals)`

It makes no sense to call `inverse_transform()` on the transformed data.

`inverse_transform()` is a method of scikit-learn transformers. But `self.encodings[key]` will give out a ndarray, because you have saved the output array from `fit_transform()`.

2) Something similar to 2 is also happening with `one_hot_encoder()`

The error `"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fit'"` seems related to 1 and 2.

Comment: I want to upvote this answer -- but points 2) and 3) miss the scope of the question entirely, and will upvote as soon as answer is edited. 

The issue with .fit() was that it was related to the build_fn argument pointing to the model and not the function itself (as you said)

The other two points you mentioned are not called at all during this process and are unrelated to the issue presented (I know we need to preprocess before fitting, this was just to make sure the model was correctly compiled)

Comment: @codebrotherone I have rejected your edit and edited the answer myself to make it clear. Have a look at it.

Comment: cool sounds good -- I had already fixed the encoding issue by the time these edits were made but I appreciate your generosity!
I will say that those errors do not conflict or are related to the problem that was initially proposed with the fit() method which has no dependency on the encodings (until the data starts processing). The whole thing here was to ensure it would compile, but I'll go ahead and mark this as acceptable answer

Nonetheless Thanks for your help! :)